# How to cross reference arrays and get the index when using an uploaded text file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, triangular

I am working on something that will import a text file with a sequence of numbers, separate the numbers from the strings and save to two separate arrays, then compare the numbers array to a third array that holds the triangular sequence of numbers in it. Once the numbers array matches with a number from the triangular sequence, the out put will be an index number of inside the number array. After, using the index number, will reference it to the text and pull the index numbers of that string array.

A visual explanation of what the process I want:

[visual example of what i am going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLwYX.png)

I am stuck on how to move to each 'step' of the process. How can I compare the sequence to the numArray and how do I get a reusable output of the index that I can later use to resort the text array? The key is that the data is coming from a text file, being split into an array (numArray), and then being indexed. I keep get undefined and [-1].

I'm almost certain this is easier to do with python or another language, if this isn't possible with vanilla js, then I honestly learn something that's more suitable.

Thank you for any help. I am very new to all this.

Below is the code I have so far.

EDIT: i changeded ap[0] to ap[n] which saves the sequence to an array.

```
    for (let n=1; n <= 300; n++) {
        //create an array to store our triangular sequence
        let ap =[] 

        //generates our triangular sequence
         ap[n] = n * (n + 1) / 2 //generates our triangular sequence

       //cycles through our array of numbers and should compare and output the value
       for (let i=0; i <= arrayNum.length; i++) {
        arrayNum[0] = i
        if (arrayNum[i] == ap[n]){
            results = ap.map(i=>arrayNum.indexOf(i))
            console.log(results)
            
        
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never store the triangular sequence. The only entry in `ap` that every gets a value assigned to it is `ap[0]`.

Comment: Your question mixes input concerns with the algorithmic part. Since you have no problem with file processing nor with HTML, you should reduce your question to just using an array input (which can be hardcoded) and producing an output from that.

Comment: The image is not clear. Please explain with a clear example in text format.

Comment: Your `//cycles through our array of numbers` code looks like it should work, but it does *not* want to be inside the "generate triangular numbers" loop.

Comment: @trincot i made these changes to the code. We have the sequence in an array now. Also simplified the example and clarified the visual. Hopefully this satisfies your requests.

Comment: @JoshuaG you overwrite the array on each iteration: `let ap =[]`. That is, you have an array with one value all the time. Take the array declaration outside the loop. Also: for `(let n=1; n <= 300; n++)` will cause the first value to be empty. Since the null element is not set. If the question is relevant, please let me know and I will try to answer it?